# Tadpoles in sigma models

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, sigma-models

In some QFTs, the tadpoles are not taken into account, since they vanish due to certain symmetries of the theory. Peskin and Schröder address this issue in QED around Equation (10.5) of their book; later they argue that same is valid in QCD.

In a general QFT, this is no longer the case. For example, in the linear sigma-models such diagrams exist in principle, but can be ignored with the use of a special renormalization prescription, see *Ibid*. (11.17).

Does anybody have an idea of what the situation is with non-linear sigma models (NLSM)? The three main cases of interest are:

1. NLSMs without gauge fields — à la $\mathbb{O}(N)$:
   $$\mathcal{L} = g_{ab}(\phi)\partial^\mu\phi^a\partial_\mu\phi^b$$
2. NLSMs with gauge fields — à la $\mathbb{CP}(N)$
   (more generally, Kähler chiral models, e.g. Grassmanian $\mathbb{G}(M,N)$ model):
   $$\mathcal{L} = g_{ab}(\phi)(\mathcal{D}^\mu\phi^a)^\dagger\mathcal{D}_\mu\phi^b$$
3. NLSMs with the WZNW term.

To me, the second case if of main interest. I'm assuming that the theory is being solved in the gauge formulation, which implies that both Lagrange multipliers and gauge fields acquire mass dynamically, and, so, the tadpoles can be, in particular, of such form:
[image]

(with wiggly line being, as usually, the gauge field)

It would also be interesting to know how supersymmetrizing NLSMs affects the physics of tadpoles.